# Hide Header for custom (/) page odoo v12

Tags: xml, frontend, odoo, odoo-12

I want to hide the header (Menu) of my Website for some page

Example:
When I open the first page of my site I find just a small portal

[image]

If I click on home it will show me the home page with the normal Header (Menu)
 [image]

What are the steps to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all 
i find solution 
it's easy to create a template for the homepage without the call of website.layout

for exemple the normal Template for website :

```
<template id="index" name="home page">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
        <div id="wrap" class="js_blog website_blog">
            <t t-raw="0"/>
               <p> Home page </p>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

if without the header and the footer with a completely white page:

```
    <template id="index" name="home page">

        <div id="wrap" class="js_blog website_blog">
            <t t-raw="0" />
            <p> Home page </p>
              ..... add what you want
        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: It deletes all Bootstrap styles :c